# Using a scroll in a xamarin.forms listview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms.listview

I am returning about 20 rows of  data in my listview and it is just showing 12.
How can I introduce a scroll in my listview  below. I tried putting a scrollview around it but no luck.

```
     <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
                            <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" Placeholder="Search" SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"/>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                    <ListView x:Name="dataList"  BackgroundColor="White">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ViewCell>
                                                    <Label FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding HeadLines}"></Label>
                                                </ViewCell>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Your XAML structure is wrong. Please have a look my code, and try it. Hope, It will help you.

**Code**

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SearchBar Grid.Column="0" x:Name="searchBar" Placeholder="Search" SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}" />
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" x:Name="dataList" BackgroundColor="White">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding HeadLines}">
                    </Label>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The question is to assist with scrolling in a listview. where is the scroll in your corrected xaml?

Comment: You shouldn't have one scrollable thing inside another. And why you want scrollview?

Comment: Agree, shouldn't have a need for a scrollview given the listview will auto scroll.  But you could have improved the answer by specifically pointing out what was wrong with the Xaml